# how to pass external .css into jsp? (path issue)

Tags: css, jsp

So far I have the following structure of my begining project: http://screenshot.cz/NQKZW/
-and what path should i type into the link tag in my index.jsp file?

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/WEB-INF/css/styles.css">
```

-this is not working, I've already tried a lot of combinations, but i was unable to give the correct path. thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this page : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23195317/accessing-resources-from-jsp-inside-web-inf
and at this one too :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752246/problem-with-using-css-in-a-jsp-file-of-dynamic-web-project?rq=1

Comment: OK guys thanks, I just took the css folder outside from WEB-INF folder, and now it's working, I didn't know i should have my resources outside of that folder.