# Image inside war not displayed on JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

I know, that there are already several of similar questions but none of them fix my problem.
I have a simple JSP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Home Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>    
      <jsp:include page="_menu.jsp"></jsp:include>    
      <h3>Home Page</h3>   
      <table>
            <tr>
               <td>aha</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         ${data.image}      
         <img src="images/wappen.jpg"/>   
         <img src="/images/wappen.jpg"/>   
         <img src="../images/wappen.jpg" alt=""/>   
   </body>
</html>
```

none of the images is displayed.
JSP is located in war in WEB-INF/views
jpg is located in war in folder images.

**Directory structure**:

```
-WebContent
 - images (here are my jpgs)
 - META-INF 
 - WEB-INF 
   - lib 
   - views (here are my jsps located)
```

The jsp is called via webServlet:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/homeView.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: what is your folder structure?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23195317/accessing-resources-from-jsp-inside-web-inf) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321952/read-the-file-from-webcontent-images-instead-of-web-inf) might help you .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the correct way, but at least I found a solution:

create a webservlet to handle the context Images:

- retrieve the requested image
- build the absolute filename of the image
- load the image from disk
- return as response

  import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
  import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
  import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;

  import javax.servlet.ServletException;
  import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
  import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

  import org.slf4j.ext.XLogger;
  import org.slf4j.ext.XLoggerFactory;

  @WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/Images/*" })
  public class DisplayImageServlet extends HttpServlet {
      /** holds the logger */
      final XLogger logger = XLoggerFactory.getXLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());

  ```
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  ```

  public DisplayImageServlet() {
        super();
    }

  @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

  ```
    String realRootPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
      String servletPath = req.getServletPath();
      String image = req.getRequestURI();
      String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();

      logger.debug("realRootPath = " + realRootPath);
      logger.debug("servletPath = " + servletPath);
      logger.debug("image = " + image);
      logger.debug("pathInfo = " + pathInfo);
      String imageRealPath = realRootPath +servletPath+pathInfo;

      logger.debug("imageRealPath = " + imageRealPath);
      response.setContentType("image/jpeg");  
      ServletOutputStream out;  
      out = response.getOutputStream();  
      FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(imageRealPath);  

      BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);  
      BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(out);  
      int ch =0; ;  
      while((ch=bin.read())!=-1)  
      {  
          bout.write(ch);  
      }  

      bin.close();  
      fin.close();  
      bout.close();  
      out.close();
  ```

  }

  @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.debug("doPost");
        doGet(request, response);
    }

  }